# How to disable cache for a block in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, cache

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mpanel/products')
    ->setProductsCount($this->getProductsCount())
    ->setCountPerRow($this->getCountPerRow())
    ->setLoadMore($this->getLoadMore())
    ->setTemplate('mgs/mpanel/products/grid/featured_products.phtml')
    ->toHtml();
```

How I can disable cache for the above block call.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

`setCacheLifeTime` to `null` and then your block will not be cache

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mpanel/products')
    ->setCacheLifetime('null') //setCacheLifeTime to 0
    ->setProductsCount($this->getProductsCount())
    ->setCountPerRow($this->getCountPerRow())
    ->setLoadMore($this->getLoadMore())
    ->setTemplate('mgs/mpanel/products/grid/featured_products.phtml')
    ->toHtml();
```

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: @KarnaSaradar try with null

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code.

```
<reference name="Your_Block">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action>
</reference>
```